# What is the difference in conditions of a free electron in metal and a isolated free electron in space-time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am asking that what environment does the free electrons in metal have,what is net electric fields,force experienced by them.does they have transitions like valence electrons.can they be compared to an isolated electron?.

Comment: Here is what you can read up on : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_wave

Comment: This question is arguably asking for a substantial fraction of solid state physics.

Answer (score 0):

The [free electron model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_electron_model) (FEM) was derived mostly by Sommerfeld in 1927. It does not yield band structures, so there's no energy bands, i.e. it cannot predict the existence of insulators and semiconductors. For such a description, one has to look at the [nearly free electron model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearly_free_electron_model), which is able to describe energy bands.

In the FEM, the electrons have to satisfy Pauli's exclusion principle, so they cannot have any energy, unlike in the case of an isolated free electron in vacuum. Also, the electron-electron interaction is ignored, so there's no electric field involved in the Hamiltonian of the FEM.

One difference between the FEM and an isolated electron is the concept of temperature, which is well defined in the former case, but not in the latter. At absolute zero temperature, there is a maximum energy the electrons can possibly have in a metal, called the [Fermi energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_energy). But in the electron in vacuum case, the concept of temperature is ill defined.

Comment: Then can I use thomson scattering cross for these electrons too because thomson scattering cross section is derived for an charge in space-time and  you say they both are essential same

Comment: I'm not saying that they are the same. The electrons in a metal have to satisfy the Pauli exclusion principle and are bounded to the metal. This is in contrast to a free electron in vacuum. Nonetheless, according to wikipedia, you can indeed apply Thomson scattering analysis to electrons in a metal. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_crystallography#Scattering.